# Why is Toolkit returning the wrong screen resolution?

Tags: java, window, screen, display, toolkit

I am currently working on a Java project which requires me to make a full screen JFrame. While I am able to make it full screen (I have used at various points both window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) and com.apple.eawt.Application's setWindowFullScreen method), the window is startlingly low resolution.

I believe the cause may be related to the size that Toolkit is returning for the screen, but I am unsure how to fix it. Toolkit reports that my screen resolution is 1280x800, but after checking About My Mac and the online specs of my laptop I am positive that my screen size is actually 2560x1600. I am using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015). Why is Toolkit returning the wrong screen size, and is this why the window is so low resolution?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with software scaling the OS might perform